# SQLite request with double grouping

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, group-by

I have a db with one column indicating the name of a person, one column the task and a third with the year of that task:

| person | task | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | task 1 | 2017 |
| Bill | task 2 | 2017 |
| Bill | task 2 | 2018 |
| Hanna | task 2 | 2019 |
| Hanna | task 0 | 2016 |
| ... |  |  |

Now I want to use sqlite to get it to show the total number of tasks per year per person and order it by year, so:

| person | year | tasks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hanna | 2016 | 1 |
| Bill | 2017 | 2 |
| Bill | 2018 | 1 |
| Hanna | 2019 | 1 |

My request:

```
SELECT author, year, count(year) as tasks
FROM db
GROUP BY author, year
ORDER BY author, year ASC;
```

But this creates an order by author, not by year.
Flipping author and year in the ORDER BY section doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this "does not work"

```
 SELECT author, year, count(year) as tasks
 FROM db
 GROUP BY author, year
 ORDER BY year ASC, author;
```

try this

```
 SELECT author, year, tasks
 FROM (
   SELECT author, year, count(year) as tasks
   FROM db
   GROUP BY author, year
 ) X
 ORDER BY year ASC, author;
```